# How to trigger windows error recovery for sure?

Tags: windows, winapi, window, recovery

I have a Windows application where I have registered a callback using the `RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback()` function.

I want to trigger my callback and test if it is actually being hit or not.

I have tried to generate an infinite loop in `main()` but the Windows Recovery dialog doesn't come up.

I know causing a segmentation fault or other related error would trigger it, but I can't trigger a segmentation fault as all of such things are handled by a seperate process which catches all crashes.

I tried an infinite loop using `for(;;)`, but the application just freezes and WER is not triggering. I was expecting to trigger the Windows Recovery dialog.

Comment: An infinite loop is not an application failure, so why would you think it would trigger a recovery? WER is triggered only if the application exits unexpectedly due to an uncaught crash, so that is what you have to do. Whatever "other process" you are referring to that "catches all errors" (how?), you are going to have to disable it so WER can handle the error instead

Comment: As per Microsoft documentation, it also trigger when app is unresponsive.

Comment: Then, you need to provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried that is not working for you.

Comment: "An infinite loop in `main()`" tells me that you are not a GUI process. GUI processes have to remain "responsive" to GUI messages. Console messages don't process GUI messages. It's not uncommon for console processes to run a long time consuming high CPU (e.g., a compiler). The system is fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

As @RaymondChen said, it's hard to define unresponsive for console applications but for GUI applications. I can build the recovery scenario for infinite loop using [Registering for Application Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerapplicationrecoverycallback) sample.
[image: Unresponsive]
[image: Restarted]

Comment: Great, thanks. I was looking for something like this?

Comment: @Sac Typically, console application is unresponsive which means the console UI that is not the scope of console application is unresponsive.